# C++/CLI invoke function from C# Dll with a callback function as the parameter

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I manage to call C# dll from my c++ code as bellow,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


#using "../Release/ClassLibrary1.dll"

using namespace ClassLibrary1;
using namespace System;


int main()
{
    int sum, x, y;
    x = 100000;
    y = 22;
    Class1 ^a = gcnew Class1();
    sum = a->demoAdd(x, y);
    sum = x + y;
    printf("%d", sum);

}

int ttt(std::string &str1) {

}
```

And this is the C# Dll,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int demoAdd(int x, int y)
        {
            int sum;
            sum = x + y;
            return sum;
        }

        public bool RunTheMethod(Func<string, int> myMethodName)
        {
            //... do stuff
            int i = myMethodName("My String");
            //... do more stuff
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

The `demoAdd` works like a charm, however, I don't know if it is possible to call `RunTheMethod` which requires a function as parameter from C++ side.

I tried as below with no luck,

```
int main()
{
    int sum, x, y;
    x = 100000;
    y = 22;
    Class1 ^a = gcnew Class1();
    sum = a->demoAdd(x, y);
    sum = x + y;
    printf("%d", sum);


    a->RunTheMethod(&ttt);

    return 0;
}

int ttt(std::string &str1) {

}
```

I'm a newbie to c++, is that possible to make that call happen?

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Your function in C# accepts a string from .NET framework, which is not native std::string of your ttt. It is probably System::String^ the one to use in ttt. I expect there might be other problems as well.

Comment: @armagedescu I modified parameter type as you suggested to System::String, however, it still complains, I have attached the error screenshot

Comment: This is not actually C++, the language extension is named C++/CLI.  Which permits you to create a Func<> delegate with gcnew, just like C# does.  You'd better first check if that is actually what you meant to accomplish.

Comment: @Neeson.Z I am not exactly sure about that, but in C# the functions are members of classes. There are no global functions as in C++. Try to create a class, add the function inside, create an instance of the class, and then pass the member function of that instance. The C++ global functions work differently and are called differently.

Comment: See this link how you create .NET classes in managed C++. You should create a managed class, add a function, create an instance and then use it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-define-and-consume-classes-and-structs-cpp-cli?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Object_instantiation
Otherwise you will have to create a dll, import it into C+ with fully specifying the native calling conventions. After that you can call, but I would not expect to use in places of lambdas.